# Setting up git commit hook for Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, redmine, githooks, gitolite

I am trying to migrate the setup here at the office from SVN to Git and am setting up Redmine as the host for our projects and issue management (Currently we use a version of Gforge + SVN).  I should preface by saying that I'm an embedded C software developer by day and have basically zero experience with Rails or web apps, but I like trying new things so I volunteered to set up the project management tools which will take us into the future.

I have Redmine setup and am using Gitolite as the Git repo manager.  Additionally, I am using the [ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting](https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting) plugin to facilitate automatic public ssh key pushing to Gitolite and automatic repo creation when we register a new project.  Everything seems to work except the repo view within the project does not keep track of the changesets.  (The "History" is just empty, although when you view the files, it does show the latest version correctly)

I copied the post-receive hook from the plugin's contrib directory to the .gitolite/ common hooks, but again I know little about Ruby and how these gitolite hooks work so I don't know how to debug this.  I notice there are log messages and things in the hook, but I have no idea where those are printed, etc...

I even tried the Howto on the Redmine wiki, [HowTo setup automatic refresh of repositories in Redmine on commit](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit):

```
#!/bin/sh

curl "http://<redmine url>/sys/fetch_changesets?key=<your service key>"
```

Any ideas on where I start debugging?  I've been able to resolve every problem up to this point, but I'm a little stuck now.  The plugin doesn't make it obvious how this is supposed to work, and to be honest, I'm not even sure if this is a problem with Redmine not reading the repo correctly (or at all), or gitolite not communicating as Redmine expects, etc...

Comment: You could try running that command if your on Linux and it would allow you to isolate the command from any git problems. Why not run `curl "http://<redmine url>/sys/fetch_changesets?key=<your service key>"
` or simply visit the URL in your web browser and see if it pulls the changesets.

Comment: I have tried that. It gives me a blank page, which to me says that it's working (if I put the wrong URL to service key, I get an error message in the browser), but I see no difference in the repository/revisions view of my project.

Comment: Well the blank page should be no issue, it seems that something is wrong with your configuration. Let me see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I could answer this...

I checked the issues under the Github page and I found this on:

https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting/issues/89

Which was pretty much exactly my problem. This does appear to be a small bug in the plugin, but you can work around it by changing Max Cache Time to "1 minute or until next commit".  This immediately fixed my problem.  I simply left it like that but one of the posters claimed that you could change it back to until next commit and it works from then on...